# How to make it fully visible of text in Winforms in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, button

[Issue to Fix this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FagwY.png)

Words are not fully visible in the button text. How to make it fully visible to and clear to all?

Words are split vertically where the background color of button which is consumed the half of the bottom color into favour of bg color. while only visible the half of defined color (light green).

In other words, half light green and half black of background vertically.

Please give the answers. Thanks in advance to all of you

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what you want because of your slightly broken English (not your fault, obviously) but it looks like the control is simply not big enough for their content.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "Padding" property in the button

Comment: Thanks though! I am changed the value of size instead the Padding!